# Permission Create|Read|Edit|Delete Page Interactions depends on permission(s): Read Pages

Tags: profile, security, permission-sets

I get the below error while I was trying to edit an existing profile,
I want to allow read, create, edit and View All access to this object via the profile, However this object is not a detail of a master detail R/S.

Can someone explain this error and of course a solution as well,

- how could I debug this issue?
- What are Page Interactions mentioned in this error?

Please explain!

Thanks and appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Consoles?  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_setup_log.htm&language=en_US

Comment: do you have atleast `read` permission to the master object?

Comment: what is the permission do you have in "Pages' object?

Comment: Refer this link, hope it might help you, http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206610&language=en_US

Comment: @SantanuBoral this is not a master detail R/S, according to your previous comment I gave read access to Pages object and the problem solved, I actually thought this refers to a VisualForce page, finally realised its another object from a manage package and requires permission.